# Reading a text file separated by dotted lines in C#

Tags: c#, .net

The text in my application's log file is separated by ---- dotted lines. I am reading that text as one single string.

The string is like this :

```
8/23 17:40:54:761  6948 - AUDIT - Logging: Set ABC
-----------------------------------------
08/23 17:40:54:772  6948 - TRANSACTION - Logging: FullFileName:/XYZ/
                           Message:Some Message 
                           Type : Information                          
---------------------------------------------
08/23 17:40:54:844  6948 - INFO - Logging: End of Control_Loaded
```

How can I convert this single string into an array or list of strings such that each string has a paragraph between the dotted lines. For example : AUDIT paragraph as string[0], TRANSACTION paragraph as string [1] and so on ....till the end paragraph where there is no dotted line at last.

**This is what I tried :**

```
     string textFromFile = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            
     string[] paragraphs = textFromFile.Split(
     new char[] { '-','-','-','-','-','-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't post the text as an image. We can't test from images. Always paste as text.

Comment: @DotNetSpartan No, comments have no influence on the up/downvotes

Comment: You shuld now also edit the description as it does not match with the sample any more (e.g. there is no "Audit" paragraph)

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks, I've edited the question to match with the sample.

Comment: If you have control of the write side of this, please change it. Taking a log that's been designed for machine consumption and making it look nice for humans tends to be simple. Taking a log that's been designed for human consumption and having a machine make sense of it is a lot harder.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar : I've updated the question with what I've tried but it doesn't works.

Comment: Why not read line by line and then check if you have `line.All(c => c == '-')` to determine if you have a break line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadParagraphs(IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    var output = new List<string>();
    foreach (var line in source)
    {
        if (line == "---------------------------------------------")
        {
            if (output.Count > 0)
            {
                yield return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, output);
                output.Clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output.Add(line);
        }
    }
    if (output.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `line == "-------"`?

Comment: @DotNetSpartan: The minimal effort of figuring out how to split a string into its constituent lines is on you. This is not a code-writing service, it's a question answering service, and what you point out is way too trivially googleable.

Comment: @Flater - I do know how this site works. OPs should not ask us to write their code, but I'm quite at liberty to do so, should I feel the desire. Please post the google link you talk about.

Comment: @KlausGütter - Initially the OP posted an image of the text. Not testing my answer was the danger of not having actual text to test with.